# Android api 28 night mode

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I was using night mode in my app and it worked fine. I was running below code in main activity when App starts and it was switching all activities to night mode styles, but with `API 28` now just main activity uses night mode and the rest day mode. I wonder what changed and where could I read more about it because it doesn't seem that changes were made for night mode with `API 28` **(Testing on emulator not on real device)**.

```
delegate.setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```